# Grant in advance privileges on Schema A for dynamically created tables on Schema B in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql

I have the following scenario in my Oracle Database (11g) and I am trying to work around grants and access privileges.

***Note*** that the following is just a Minimum Viable Example and it does not cover the complete logic of what my program will do.

What I have

- MyMainSchema: this schema has several tables in it
- MyProcs: this schema has only several procedures in it. Every time I create a table in MyMainSchema I (manually) give S I D U in MyProcs for that table.
- MyPlaceHolder: this schema is empty

I have a package and a procedure in MyProcs, which all it does is to

- read data from MyMainSchema
- create a new table in MyPlaceHolder
- insert data in this newly created table
- drops this newly created table

To achieve what I want, my solution until now is

- run as MyProcs user
- read data from MyMainSchema
- alter session and switch to MyPlaceHolder user
- create a new table in MyPlaceHolder
- issue a grant to give S I D U permissions to MyProcs on the newly created table
- alter session and switch to MyPlaceHolder user
- insert data in this newly created table
- do some processing
- (at some point) drops this newly created table

I am trying to avoid the user / schema switch and the grant commands.

**My question is:** Is there a command (or more) that it will run only once and it will result the following:

- MyProcs will have the ability to create and drop any table new or old in MyPlaceHolder.
- MyProcs will 'automatically' have S I D U permissions on any table that is created in MyPlaceHolder

Comment: Why not create the tables in `MyProc`? This can be done by setting the `PACKAGE` in `MyPlaceHolder`as `AUTHID CURRENT_USER`.

Comment: @MichaelKutz is a requirement of my project to keep this setup and Procedures and Tables in separate schemas. Your proposal will work, however I can not apply it in this specific case.